# High memory usage by msedgewebview2.exe every few days

Tags: windows, windows-11, microsoft-edge, memory-leaks

It doesn't happen everyday, so it's hard to investigate.

Every few days, my running applications would crash because of low memory. When I try to investigate, I see `msedgewebview2.exe` having high memory usage. But before I can do anything, it usually terminates on its own, so I am not able to research more.

Note: I noticed it's process description said something like "COM surrogate". I mentioned this because there are other instances of the application running but they have different description

[image]

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to be more careful and started observing my memory usage more frequently.

Eventually, I found the memory hogger by looking at the command line of process, taking too much memory. The issue was [Explorer Patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge WebView2 is essentially used to embed web pages in
native applications. It's used in the Windows 11 Widgets app for showing
news stories and also by Microsoft teams.

If you wish to reclaim the memory back, there are several methods:

- With Task Manager, terminate the processes of "Windows Widgets" and
  "Microsoft Teams"
- Disable Microsoft Teams on Startup
- Disable Windows Widgets using Windows Registry, key
  `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3078088237-2142244905-4044066433-1002\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Dsh`, setting `IsPrelaunchEnabled` to `0`
- Uninstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 via Third-Party Utility such as
  [Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/).
  This might affect other applications than just Microsoft Edge WebView2
  and Teams.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Fix “MSEDGEWEBVIEW2.EXE” Consuming Memory in Windows 11?](https://appuals.com/msedgewebview2-exe-consuming-memory-windows-11/)

Comment: But how did you conclude it's Window Widget or Teams causing the issue?

Comment: They are indicated in several articles as great users of WebView2 under Windows 11. I'm not saying that this is surely your problem, just that this is one solution that worked for some people.